# How to get colors with the same perceived brightness?

Tags: colors, brightness, luminance

Is there a tool / program / color system that enables you to get colors of the same luminance (perceived brightness)?

Say I pick a color (determine RGB values) and the program gives me all the colors around the color wheel with the same luminance but different hues?

I haven't seen such tool yet, all I came across were three different algorithms for color luminance:

```
(0.2126*R) + (0.7152*G) + (0.0722*B)
(0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B)
sqrt( 0.241*R^2 + 0.691*G^2 + 0.068*B^2 )
```

Just to be clear, I'm talking about color luminance / perceived brightness or whatever you want to call it - the attribute that encounters that we perceive red hue brighter than blue for example. (So 255,0,0 has higher luminance value than 0,0,255.)

P.S.: Does anyone know which algorithm is used to determine color luminence on this website: http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-picker-01.htm
It looks like they used none of the posted algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

In the HSL color picker you linked to, it looks like they are using the 3rd Lightness equation given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Lightness), and then making it a percentage.  So the equation is:

```
L = (100 * 0.5 * (max(r,g,b) + min(r,g,b))) / 255
```

**Edit:** Actually, I just realized that they have an `L` value and a `Lum` value shown on that color picker.  The equation above applies to the `L` value, but I don't know how they are arriving at the `Lum` value.  It doesn't seem to follow any of the standard equations.

Comment: Yeah, but that's how they get lightness, not luminance. The luminance value is the one above the big color rectangle - Lum, not L

Comment: exactly what I just ran into.  No idea how to calculate their Lum value in %.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689952/how-to-determine-luminance-of-a-color-in-grayscale