# How to determine luminance %?

Tags: algorithm, colors, rgb, formula, luminance

According to http://www.workwithcolor.com/color-luminance-2233.htm, RED (#FF0000) has Luminance: 54%. and light pink (#FF8080) has Luminance: 89%.  Our designers like it but how is it determined?  Try here: http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-schemer-01.htm

I tried using [relative luminance formula published by W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#relativeluminancedef) and although the range is [0,1], red is `0.21` and white is `1.00`.

I'm thinking, maybe what workwithcolor does is first covert the color into grayscale, and read the luminance of the gray.  I tried it but it still doesn't give the same result.

I've tried so far : http://jsfiddle.net/HytZQ/

Comment: Here's what [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance_(relative)) says about relative luminance.

Comment: Found this JS library that does Luminance() http://tech.pusherhq.com/libraries/color based on the W3C css color definition.

Comment: I like the results shown in your link. They don't appear to use any of the usual suspects for the conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the formula here:
[Formula to determine brightness of RGB color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color)

```
Luminance (standard, objective): (0.2126*R) + (0.7152*G) + (0.0722*B)
```

Put R=255, and G=B=0, you'll get 54

**Edit:**
For relative luminance, divide by the maximum (255)
you get 21%

For white, you get 100%

Comment: Thx Jerry, I think you're right, but luminance % in the workwithcolor link I posted in the question seems to be doing a different thing.  So while you're right, I think I asked the question wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: Somehow workwithcolor's formula would return Lum 54% for red, 89% for light pink, and 100% for white.  The relative luminance formula can only return either 21% for red & 100% for white, or 54% for red & 255% for white.

Answer (score 3):

Luminance, Luminosity and Brightness are not the same thing. HSL color model would be great to understand that where one of the component is L (luminosity).

Luminance is not something that you should care about as per your requirement. please read the discussion in the link:

http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/forums/thread23366.htm

RED (#FF0000) has the luminosity as 50% at 100% saturation, but the software programs that we use adjust the values slightly to consider the perceptive factors.

What you need is to start with pure colors. A pure colors are the colors in HSL color space which have luminosity as 50% and saturation as 100% and changing the value of hue gives you the pure colors. There are a total of 6*60 pure colors available via HSL/RGB color spaces. i.e. if you sum the colors generated using the combinations below you will get 360 pure colors.

R=255*(x/60), G=0, B=255; where x changes from 0 to 60
R=255*(x/60), G=255, B=0; where x changes from 0 to 60

R=255, G=255*(x/60), B=0; where x changes from 0 to 60
R=0, G=255*(x/60), B=255; where x changes from 0 to 60

R=255, G=0, B=255*(x/60); where x changes from 0 to 60
R=0, G=255, B=255*(x/60); where x changes from 0 to 60

rest all the colors we see are manipulation of saturation and luminosity.

Now,
To get the gray scale images:

1 - You can use the brightness formula as suggested by Jerry (there are some other formulae for better performance).
2 - You can change the saturation to 0% in HSL color space which is exactly http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-schemer-01.htm does.

Answer (score 0):

[These questions are similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75904122/13843985), so I post the same answer on both.

A way to get the values they show is transforming the colour from [sRGB to CIE-XYZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#From_sRGB_to_CIE_XYZ) and then from [CIE-XYZ to L*a*b* (or CIELAB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space#Converting_between_CIELAB_and_CIEXYZ_coordinates)

In CIELAB, **L*** is described as perceptual lightness, that's the value the page shows as Luminance.

You can calculate this value quickly with the following equations, remember that the RGB values must need to be normalized (values from 0 to 1):

[image: Equations]

Here is a comparison between this algorithm (**L***) and the one in the page (**Lum.**) using the colours on the [color luminance explanation](http://www.workwithcolor.com/color-luminance-2233.htm).

| Color | **L*** [%] | **Lum.** [%] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `#FF0000` | 53.232881... | 54 (53.77) |
| `#FF8000` | 67.050096... | 65 (65.06) |
| `#FFFF00` | 97.138246... | 94 (93.63) |
| `#80FF00` | 89.910015... | 83 (82.96) |
| `#00FF00` | 87.737033... | 80 (79.52) |
| `#00FF80` | 88.485146... | 82 (81.63) |
| `#00FFFF` | 91.116521... | 87 (87.44) |
| `#0080FF` | 54.718662... | 57 (57.36) |
| `#0000FF` | 32.302586... | 44 (43.95) |
| `#8000FF` | 40.911243... | 52 (51.51) |
| `#FF00FF` | 60.319933... | 70 (70.28) |
| `#FF0080` | 54.884906... | 60 (59.59) |

For `#FF8080` I get %68.209498... (Page shows %69 (%68.60)), but you stated that the value is %89, I assume this is a typo.