# How to calculate luminance in HSL

Tags: hsl

Just checked this website http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-schemer-01.htm and I am curious how to get those numbers in Lum(luminance)? I can not find a proper formula online to get those results. Thanks

Comment: Red in RGB is (255,0,0), by the formula luminance of red color is (0+255)/510 = 0.5 = 50% but that website says that the Lum of red is 54%. And blue and green all have 50% as Luminance by this formula. So the results do not match. That's why I am curious about their result.

Comment: Ah, on another computer I can see that site. There is a difference between the lightness in HSL and "luma", as shown in the Wikipedia article [HSL and HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Lightness). Looking at the JavaScript on the site you're looking at, they use lum = 0.2126R + 0.7152G + 0.0722B, corresponding to sRGB.

Comment: yes, I saw that equation is used in a function in the script, but can't find what calls this function. but thanks!

Comment: In that case I do not understand what your question is. Are you asking where that function is called in the code on that page?

Answer (score 0):

A way to get the values they show is transforming the colour from [sRGB to CIE-XYZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#From_sRGB_to_CIE_XYZ) and then from [CIE-XYZ to L*a*b* (or CIELAB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space#Converting_between_CIELAB_and_CIEXYZ_coordinates)

In CIELAB, **L*** is described as perceptual lightness, that's the value the page shows as Luminance.

You can calculate this value quickly with the following equations, remember that the RGB values must need to be normalized (values from 0 to 1):

[image: Equations]

Here is a comparison between this algorithm (**L***) and the one in the page (**Lum.**) using the colours on the [color luminance explanation](http://www.workwithcolor.com/color-luminance-2233.htm).

| Color | **L*** [%] | **Lum.** [%] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `#FF0000` | 53.232881... | 54 (53.77) |
| `#FF8000` | 67.050096... | 65 (65.06) |
| `#FFFF00` | 97.138246... | 94 (93.63) |
| `#80FF00` | 89.910015... | 83 (82.96) |
| `#00FF00` | 87.737033... | 80 (79.52) |
| `#00FF80` | 88.485146... | 82 (81.63) |
| `#00FFFF` | 91.116521... | 87 (87.44) |
| `#0080FF` | 54.718662... | 57 (57.36) |
| `#0000FF` | 32.302586... | 44 (43.95) |
| `#8000FF` | 40.911243... | 52 (51.51) |
| `#FF00FF` | 60.319933... | 70 (70.28) |
| `#FF0080` | 54.884906... | 60 (59.59) |